# playing mp3 file even when distributed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mp3

(2015-12-06)
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 C# and I'm wondering how I can let the program play an MP3 file as a background music, even when it's distributed to someone else's computer (and not just on my computer with the my own path of the MP3 file - e.g. `c:\my documents\so and so music.mp3`).

(2015-12-07)
Thanks to Maximilian Gerhardt for the kind reply. But when I tried with my own out.wav, I got stuck with a few red lines.. (compile errors..) And I'm not so sure how to go on. (sorry I'm new to C#)
[This is what I see - the image of the compile error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xR5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

First you create a new resource file somewhere in your project. Use the `Add -> New element` context menu in the project explorer to do that:
[image]
(yes, sorry, that's in german.)

Once you created your resource file you can double-click on it in the project explorer and add resources to it. I added a `.wav` file called `out.wav`. This could be your `.mp3` file.
[image: abc]
Next you just have to access that stream in Code. Adding the resource file also generates some code which let's you access that file as a stream. Usage e.g.:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ResourceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a memory stream to read the file into..
            MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
            //Copy our _out.wav File
            SomeResource._out.CopyTo(outStream);
            //Also possible: 
            //SomeResource.ResourceManager.GetStream("out.wav")...
            //Read into a byte array.
            byte[] file_bytes = outStream.ToArray();
            //Close it
            outStream.Close();

            //Do something with file_bytes..
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you've embedded your ressource in a ressource file, it's always accessible (i.e. the resource always gets copied in your compiled binary)

Comment: Thanks for help. But unfortunately.. couldn't get it to work.. (please see the attached)

Comment: The class name `SomeResource` was derived from the name of the resource file I created (`SomeResource.resx`). You must change the classname to the filename of the resource file you created. (There's a `Resources.resx`, so you should try `Resources._out`?)

Comment: Ah ha. So that was it. I re-wrote the code and it compiles well with no errors. But then.... it plays no sounds either..  It looks like we managed to load the resource onto a memory, but how do we play the resource from the memory...? Sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: You can use the library `NAudio` to create an audio device and fill it with data, which can e.g. be from the `file_bytes[]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15025797/5296568 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/184683/5296568 .

Comment: Thanks again :). Maximilian. You're awesome