# In VB.net, is it possible to play an embedded MP3 audio file?

Tags: vb.net

When I launch my application, background music starts.
The code below allows me to get that,
provided that I integrate a WAV audio file into the resources.

Unfortunately, a WAV audio file is very heavy: my file is 40 MB.
If I used the same audio file in mp3, it would be: 2.75 MB.

Visual Basic does not accept mp3 files. Is there not a way around this problem?
Thank you for your reply.

Class MainWindow

```
'Music Background.

Private Sub Main_Form_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Main_Form.Loaded
    Dim son = New Media.SoundPlayer(My.Resources.My_Music)
    son.PlayLooping()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing a MP3 file in a WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application)

Comment: GSerg, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you GSerg, your link has allowed me to find the solution: the code below works perfectly.
Previously, install Naudio under Visual Studio. Then,
Imports System.IO - Imports NAudio.Wave

Music Background.

```
Private Sub Form_Main_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Form_Main.Loaded
    Dim mp3file As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(My.Resources.My.Music)        
    Dim mp3Reader As Mp3FileReader = New Mp3FileReader(mp3file)
    Dim waveOut As WaveOut = New WaveOut
    waveOut.Init(mp3Reader)
    waveOut.Play()
```

Another question: is there a function or an additional code to play music loop? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Good contribution providing the code for how to do it via an embedded resource.