# Detect the installed version of Windows Media Player using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, media-player

I have a C# application and I need to detect the installed version of Windows Media Player (I need to know if its higher than 10). Anyone has an idea of how I can solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to browse the registry to get the version of wmp installed

Comment: you have to check the registry value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718152/how-to-check-what-version-of-windows-media-player-is-installed-on-the-machine

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `IsInstalled` value under key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95}`. It is 1 if installed, 0 otherwise.

See [Detecting Windows Media Player from an Application.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562731%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks This works nicely. But per your link, I'm using {6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6} to check WMP ver7 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use registry via c#  to get details
Every software installed on system has registry entry in "**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**" under "**SOFTWARE**"

So we go inside and search **MediaPlayer** inside **Microsoft** folder.

There we have the folder named **PlayerUpgrade**, Inside that we have key ***PlayerVersion*** which have the version of the media player installed.

Below is the code

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MediaPlayer\\PlayerUpgrade", false);
string version = (string) myKey.GetValue("PlayerVersion");
```

you will get value like "11,0,6002,18111." means version 11

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .Net to read the file version. Example:

```
FileVersionInfo wmpInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), "Windows Media Player", "wmplayer.exe"));
if (wmpInfo.FileMajorPart > 10)
{
    //Do something
}
```